# Can't create directory - read only

Tags: permissions

I have the game Starruler 2 installed, I can not create a directory or write into the mods directory.

Path is /Snap/starrruler2/36/starruler2/mods

I have tried changing the permissions using krusader as root user.  I have tried using chmod command but I get a read-only error.  I might not be using the write options.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: 1) Is it Snap or snap? 2) Is there a reason you would need to write into that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Snap applications are, once installed, mounted as a squashfs file system under a folder `/snap/<snap name>/<revision>/`. A squashfs is a compressed read-only file system. Accordingly, it is perfectly normal and expected that you, nor the root user, can make changes to that mounted file system as this is how it works by design.

Comment: It is the game mods folder.  I can not add mods to the game unless I can write into that folder.  I would really like to.  The path is snap/starruler2/36/starruler/mods.  Seems odd the game would make a mods folder that can not be written into.

Comment: I do not know the specifics, but that is how it works for snaps. In principle you could mount a read-write file system on that mods folder. Then you would be able to place contents in it.